# Timing how long it takes to do the in operator

Tags: python, operator-keyword, timing

Here, the del operator is timed:

```
from timeit import Timer

def build_list(n):
    return list(range(n))  # create list of 1 to n


def build_dict(n): # build dict = { 0:"0", 1:"1", 2:"2", ... n:"n" }
    return {i: str(i) for i in range(n)}  # from last listing in this chapter


def inx(x,n): # do in front, middle, end, and not found
    str(0) in x
    str(n//2) in x
    str(n-1) in x
    str("a") in x # not in it

timeList = Timer(
    "inx(x,n)",
    "from __main__ import n,build_list,inx; x = build_list(n)")

timeDict = Timer(
    "inx(x,n)",
    "from __main__ import n,build_dict,inx; x = build_dict(n)")

# get min of 5 runs of 5
print("N", "\t", "List", "\t", "Dict")
for size in range(1000, 100000+1, 5000):  # sizes to graph for n:
    n = size
    list_secs = timeList.repeat(5,5)
    dict_sect = timeDict.repeat(5,5)
    print(n, "\t", min(list_secs), "\t", min(dict_sect))
```

This time, it's timing how long it takes to do the in operator and not the del operator. What codes need to be changed and added?

Comment: Those `in x` timings for the dict are a bit misleading since the time it takes to construct each of the tested strings is significant compared to performing the dict lookup. To see this, remove the `in x` from each line in `inx(x,n)`. The resulting times for just calling the `inx()` function & constructing the strings are roughly 50% of the times for doing the full test.

Comment: hmm, i can see, but is it related to timing the in operator?

Comment: Yes and no. :) The above code certainly shows that `in` is much faster on dicts than on lists of the same size. But the times it reports aren't _just_ timing the `in` operation - those times also include the time it takes to call the `inx()` function itself plus the time it takes to build the 4 strings. And that stuff takes roughly the same amount of time as doing the actual `in` operations on a dict. So the numbers that code prints shouldn't be taken as an accurate indication of the relative speed difference between doing `in` on a list vs on a dict.

Comment: So what do you recommend me to do to get my desired results?

Comment: There's no perfect solution, but the general principle is to minimize any extra work done inside the code that you're timing so that the time taken to do that extra work doesn't swamp the timing of the operations you're really trying to measure. So do as much work as possible beforehand, either in the setup code or before you call the timer methods. If you suspect that the overheads are significant compared to the actual operations you want to test (like in this case) you can create a function that just does that extra work and time it so you get an idea of how much time that stuff takes.

Comment: In this case, you could do `s = ("0", str(n//2), str(n-1), "a")` in your `for` loop, import `s` in your setup code (like you're importing `n`) & replace the `inx(x,n)` call in your Timer statements with `for v in s: v in x`. That way, you not only eliminate the overhead of building the strings you also eliminate the overhead of calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement del separately for list and dict since list takes integer to index and your dictionary has string keys. Since we can't delete an element that doesn't exist in the list or dict I omitted that part.

```
from timeit import Timer

def build_list(n):
    return list(range(n))  # create list of 1 to n


def build_dict(n): # build dict = { 0:"0", 1:"1", 2:"2", ... n:"n" }
    return {i: str(i) for i in range(n)}  # from last listing in this chapter


def delx(x, n):  # do in front, middle, end, and not found
    if x is list:
        del x[0]  # deleting first element in list
        del x[(n-1)//2]  # middle element delete n-1 because 0-th element is already deleted
        del x[-1]  # last element delete
    if x is dict:
        del x[str(0)]  # deleting first element in dict
        del x[str((n-1)//2)]  # deleting middle element from dict
        del x[str((n-2)-1)]  # last element delete n-2 because 0-th and middle element is already deleted
        # str("a") in x # not in it

timeList = Timer(
    "delx(x,n)",
    "from __main__ import n,build_list,delx; x = build_list(n)")

timeDict = Timer(
    "delx(x,n)",
    "from __main__ import n,build_dict,delx; x = build_dict(n)")

# get min of 5 runs of 5
print("N", "\t", "List", "\t", "Dict")
for size in range(1000, 100000+1, 5000):  # sizes to graph for n:
    n = size
    list_secs = timeList.repeat(5,5)
    dict_sect = timeDict.repeat(5,5)
    print(n, "\t", min(list_secs), "\t", min(dict_sect))
```

Comment: seems to be running properly. I figured it has something to do with del x. wasn't particularly 100% what to do though. Thank you very much for helping me out, k4vin.